# Bing maps control not rendering properly in IE7 - SharePoint 2010

Tags: internet-explorer-7, sharepoint-2010, bing-maps

I've created a SharePoint 2010 WebPart that pulls lat/long info from a list and displays pins in a map.  I'm having a problem where the map does not render properly in IE7.  Even when I'm not using any pins and just showing a basic map.  Here's a screenshot: [Screenshot](https://7839255702295085338-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/derrickbowen/home/Home/bingmapsproblem.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cqKFNkEJNhvVNm3gMzT817z3kGS8S9lvExn2c9SsqbpZ1Sxk6lfkEmLqriKSiitHGrhaVJ3r9j4WcaTpbWNSd949wsjubJtUA-vqiwfogGQPMfUDguCU10pOz7hpF3DWLNgngDLPma531Qoosnn7gJv0Osc9z6ampnmYJl-Ysm9tNMyB4iVywhfjehjiMTCbgWUY19uMO4iDSHPamvQaHcyS_t0DxRpefQ9jzr1IST-rBsvF6Y%3D&attredirects=0)

I've simplified the code as much as possible and am still getting the error.  here's my sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2"></script>
<div id='rowanMap' style="position:relative; width:100%; height:400px; float:none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function GetMap() {
  var map = null;
  map = new VEMap('rowanMap');
  map.SetCredentials("[Redacted]");

// pins added programatically here if they exist, but problem occurs without them as well.

  map.LoadMap();
 }

 GetMap();
</script>
```

This is being added to the page as a visual webpart.

I know it's not my version of ie7, because this demo works when loaded in a second tab: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/

Again, firefox, chrome, ie8, ie9 all work properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround.  It seems that the problem is that the getmap() function runs before the page finishes loading, so adding a timeout solves the problem:

```
 setTimeout("GetMap()", 50);
```

I tried using the window.onload method, but it overwrote some necessary sharepoint javascript.  Luckily the timeout works even when it is very short.